# .NET MAUI CollectionView has very poor scrolling performance - how do I go about troubleshooting that to see what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Before I go any further with my program, I'd like to get rid of the scrolling performance issue I'm having.

In an effort to troubleshoot, I've ended up reducing my main page down to as basic as it gets and I've still got horrible scrolling performance.  I assume this must mean that it is something in my ViewModel or code behind causing the problem.  I'm hoping someone will see something obvious I'm doing that's causing the scrolling to chug/lock up.

#### View (reduced to just the Title now)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    x:Name="PostsPage"
    Title="Posts"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Disc.Views.HomePage" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Disc"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Disc.ViewModels"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Disc.Models"
    x:DataType="vm:PostsViewModel"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Disc.Converters;assembly=Disc"
    xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <!-- Define the converter resources -->
        <converters:CommunityNameColorConverter x:Key="communityNameColor" />
        <converters:UsernameColorConverter x:Key="usernameColor" />
        <converters:CreatedAtConverter x:Key="createdAt" />
        <converters:LinkTypeImageConverter x:Key="typeToImage" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
        Order="Primary"
        IconImageSource="icon_search_darkmode.png" />
        <ToolbarItem
        Order="Primary"
        IconImageSource="icon_filter_darkmode.png" />
        <ToolbarItem
        Order="Primary"
        IconImageSource="icon_three_dots_darkmode.png" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <CollectionView
        x:Name="PostsCollection"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
        BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=WhiteSmoke, Dark=#1C1D20}"
        RemainingItemsThreshold="15"
        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate 
                x:Name="CompactView" 
                x:DataType="models:Post">
                <FlexLayout 
                    Direction="Column"
                    AlignItems="Start"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">
                    <Label 
                            FontSize="14"
                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                            MaxLines="2"
                            FontAttributes="None" 
                            />
                </FlexLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

#### Code Behind

```cs
using Disc.Services;
using Disc.ViewModels;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Disc.Views;

public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    PostsViewModel vm;

    public class LinkInfo
    {
        public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public HomePage(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {       
        var restService = serviceProvider.GetService<RestService>();
        BindingContext = vm = new PostsViewModel(serviceProvider);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await vm.LoadPosts();
        //PostsCollection.ScrollTo(0);
    }

    bool IsLoadingMoreItems = false;
    async void OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsLoadingMoreItems) return;
        IsLoadingMoreItems = true;

        Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++");
        Debug.WriteLine("Threshold reached");
        Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++");
        await vm.LoadPosts();

        IsLoadingMoreItems = false;
    }

    private void OnChevronClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        // Get the image object
        ImageButton imageButton = sender as ImageButton;

        // Get the current row of the image
        int currentRow = Grid.GetRow(imageButton);

        // Get the next row
        int nextRow = currentRow + 1;

        // Add a new row definition to the grid
        Grid PostsGrid = this.FindByName<Grid>("PostsGrid"); 
        PostsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(50) });

        // Set the row of the image to the next row
        Grid.SetRow(imageButton, nextRow); 
    }

        async void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
    {

        LinkInfo linkInfo = new LinkInfo();
        linkInfo.LinkUrl = args.Parameter as string;

        if (linkInfo.LinkUrl != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Link URL: " + linkInfo.LinkUrl);

            //Check to see if URL is a direct image
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(linkInfo.LinkUrl);
            Debug.WriteLine("Link Extension: " + extension);
            if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".png" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".bmp")
            {
                // Create a new Models.Link object and set its LinkUrl property to the linkInfo.LinkUrl value
                Models.Link link = new Models.Link();
                link.LinkUrl = linkInfo.LinkUrl;

                // Create a new ImageViewModel object and pass the link.LinkUrl property to its constructor
                var VM = new ImageViewModel(link.LinkUrl);

                // Push the WebViewPage onto the navigation stack
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ImagePage(VM));
            }
            else
            {
                // Create a new Models.Link object and set its LinkUrl property to the linkInfo.LinkUrl value
                Models.Link link = new Models.Link();

                link.LinkUrl = linkInfo.LinkUrl;

                // Create a new WebViewViewModel object and pass the link.LinkUrl property to its constructor
                var VM = new WebViewViewModel(link.LinkUrl);

                // Push the WebViewPage onto the navigation stack
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new WebViewPage(VM));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Link was null");
            //SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Link was null in OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped()");
        }

    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```cs
using Disc.Models;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Disc.Services;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Disc.ViewModels;

public partial class PostsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Get Root Data
    public Root Data { get; set; }

    //Get Pagination Data
    public Root Next { get; set; }

    //Get Posts Data
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Downvotes { get; set; }

    public string IsPinned { get; set; }
    public string NoComments { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Upvotes { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //Get Post Image Data
    public Models.Image Image { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    //Get Post Link Data
    public Link Link { get; set; }
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
    public string Hostname { get; set; }

    //FetchNextData vars
    public string baseUrl { get; set; } = Constants.RestUrl;
    public string feedSort { get; set; } = "&sort=hot";
    public string endPoint { get; set; } = "/posts?limit=" + Constants.PageSize;
    public RestClient client { get; set; }

    private readonly RestService _restService;

    public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    //handle refreshing
    private bool listRefreshing = false;
    public bool ListRefreshing
    {
        get => listRefreshing;
        set => SetProperty(ref listRefreshing, value);
    }

    // constructor to initialize objects
    public PostsViewModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Setting _restService to restService");
        _restService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RestService>();

        var client = _restService.client;
        Debug.WriteLine("Client Value in constructor: " + client);

        Posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>();
    }

    public async Task LoadPosts()
    {
        string url = baseUrl + endPoint + feedSort;

        // add the parameter for Next page of data
        if (Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data.Next))
        {
            url += "&next=" + Data.Next;
        }

        var request = new RestRequest(url);
        var TotalPostsBeforePull = Posts.Count; //Total number of posts before pulling new posts

        Debug.WriteLine("Client Value in LoadPosts: " + client); ;
        var content = await _restService.client.GetAsync(request);

        //set json options
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        };

        if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            //IsLoadingMoreItems = true;
            Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);

            var NewPosts = Data.Posts.Count; //Total number of new posts grabbed

            var PostsCount = NewPosts + TotalPostsBeforePull; //Total number of posts after pulling new posts

            //var Index = NewPosts - Constants.PageSize; //Get the root index of the new posts pulled in
            var Index = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine(Index);
            while (NewPosts > Index) //while the total number of posts is greater than the total number of posts minus the limit of posts to add
            {
                Posts.Add(Data.Posts[Index]);
                Index++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
        }
    }
}
```

Anything I'm doing wrong or that is obviously what is causing the problem I'm seeing?  Thank you!!

##### UPDATE

After stripping out the 4 converters I had, and anything else I could think of to clean up the Debug output, I'm getting this as a sample of what happens in-between threshold loads - not sure if there's anything helpful in here or not.

A few things I noticed and have questions about:

1. Is it normal for it to read as [icentrobot.disc] here? My app is com.reticentrobot.disc
2. I'm not sure what these lines mean, but they seem to be appearing a lot, especially when I hit a point where it seems to lock up and really chug for a second before loading more posts:

```
[icentrobot.disc] Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
[icentrobot.disc] WaitForGcToComplete blocked Explicit on Background for 31.612ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 52789(2216KB) AllocSpace objects, 26(760KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8412KB/32MB, paused 24us,19us total 12.142ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 172557(7914KB) AllocSpace objects, 90(1912KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8389KB/32MB, paused 28us,20us total 13.934ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 262152(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 119(2428KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 9092KB/35MB, paused 30us,20us total 15.462ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 457731(18MB) AllocSpace objects, 216(4432KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 9258KB/36MB, paused 29us,17us total 15.901ms
[icentrobot.disc] Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
[icentrobot.disc] WaitForGcToComplete blocked Explicit on Background for 12.431ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 83341(3465KB) AllocSpace objects, 35(812KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 9284KB/36MB, paused 75us,23us total 15.376ms
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=1995ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=115281489, IntendedVsync=307726918962291, Vsync=307727093962284, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=307727099002141, AnimationStart=307727099004664, PerformTraversalsStart=307728879959540, DrawStart=307728881971747, FrameDeadline=307726958594804, FrameInterval=307727098994654, FrameStartTime=8333333, SyncQueued=307728901976345, SyncStart=307728902535956, IssueDrawCommandsStart=307728903277167, SwapBuffers=307728914702297, FrameCompleted=307728915160264, DequeueBufferDuration=19735, QueueBufferDuration=279581, GpuCompleted=307728915160264, SwapBuffersCompleted=307728915073187, DisplayPresentTime=307321782356232, CommandSubmissionCompleted=307728914702297, 
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 235948(9889KB) AllocSpace objects, 107(2140KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 9447KB/36MB, paused 33us,20us total 15.787ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 209307(9069KB) AllocSpace objects, 102(2152KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 9473KB/37MB, paused 32us,18us total 15.983ms
```

3. I'm seeing this every so often, but not sure what else I could possible strip out?  What am I doing wrong? `[Choreographer] Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

```
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
[0:] Threshold reached
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #14
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #12
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #16
The thread 0xf has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xe has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #18
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #19
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #20
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 533101(22MB) AllocSpace objects, 250(5000KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8026KB/31MB, paused 28us,17us total 13.128ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 416569(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 197(3988KB) LOS objects, 77% free, 7030KB/30MB, paused 35us,21us total 12.701ms
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #21
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #22
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 359289(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 192(3840KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 7882KB/31MB, paused 30us,21us total 12.772ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 317220(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 145(3012KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8098KB/31MB, paused 29us,20us total 12.174ms
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #23
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #24
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #25
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 575384(24MB) AllocSpace objects, 269(5492KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8435KB/32MB, paused 25us,24us total 13.930ms
[TrafficStats] tagSocket(114) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
[icentrobot.disc] Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
[icentrobot.disc] WaitForGcToComplete blocked Explicit on Background for 16.363ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 96344(4033KB) AllocSpace objects, 39(780KB) LOS objects, 77% free, 7184KB/31MB, paused 39us,47us total 12.694ms
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
[0:] Threshold reached
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #26
[Choreographer] Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[TrafficStats] tagSocket(125) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
[TrafficStats] tagSocket(146) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 211023(8964KB) AllocSpace objects, 92(1840KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8602KB/33MB, paused 26us,96us total 12.857ms
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #27
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 329386(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 160(3360KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8577KB/33MB, paused 59us,38us total 12.736ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 375271(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 181(4212KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8261KB/32MB, paused 26us,21us total 12.426ms
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=983ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=115272527, IntendedVsync=307370945210323, Vsync=307371495210301, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=307371495799046, AnimationStart=307371495801976, PerformTraversalsStart=307371840792943, DrawStart=307371900165135, FrameDeadline=307371378570013, FrameInterval=307371495746841, FrameStartTime=8333333, SyncQueued=307371921231094, SyncStart=307371921292211, IssueDrawCommandsStart=307371922107762, SwapBuffers=307371927992975, FrameCompleted=307371928610448, DequeueBufferDuration=23112, QueueBufferDuration=178142, GpuCompleted=307371928610448, SwapBuffersCompleted=307371928264541, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=307371927992975, 
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 307259(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 147(2940KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8058KB/31MB, paused 24us,20us total 11.875ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 226311(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 115(2300KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8019KB/31MB, paused 23us,20us total 11.569ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 146924(6211KB) AllocSpace objects, 64(1280KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 7905KB/31MB, paused 30us,20us total 11.552ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 186200(7885KB) AllocSpace objects, 81(1620KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8470KB/33MB, paused 30us,20us total 13.477ms
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=932ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=115272879, IntendedVsync=307372359422184, Vsync=307372367756269, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=307372369803889, AnimationStart=307372369819880, PerformTraversalsStart=307373249295548, DrawStart=307373259637792, FrameDeadline=307372394015960, FrameInterval=307372369797989, FrameStartTime=8334085, SyncQueued=307373277677424, SyncStart=307373277763687, IssueDrawCommandsStart=307373279023290, SwapBuffers=307373290794531, FrameCompleted=307373291664078, DequeueBufferDuration=24414, QueueBufferDuration=212850, GpuCompleted=307373291664078, SwapBuffersCompleted=307373291078344, DisplayPresentTime=1684368496, CommandSubmissionCompleted=307373290794531, 
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 393293(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 183(3708KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8698KB/33MB, paused 27us,24us total 13.226ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 249768(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 111(2332KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8434KB/32MB, paused 27us,19us total 12.541ms
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=716ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=115273154, IntendedVsync=307373415167334, Vsync=307373514981270, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=307373518352962, AnimationStart=307373518355362, PerformTraversalsStart=307374097862646, DrawStart=307374110808854, FrameDeadline=307373506603600, FrameInterval=307373518347509, FrameStartTime=8317828, SyncQueued=307374123158504, SyncStart=307374123473445, IssueDrawCommandsStart=307374124259497, SwapBuffers=307374131845556, FrameCompleted=307374132475439, DequeueBufferDuration=19898, QueueBufferDuration=490316, GpuCompleted=307374132227474, SwapBuffersCompleted=307374132475439, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=307374131845556, 
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 346171(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 167(3452KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8394KB/32MB, paused 30us,21us total 14.604ms
[icentrobot.disc] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 167729(7150KB) AllocSpace objects, 77(1540KB) LOS objects, 75% free, 8679KB/33MB, paused 27us,23us total 12.739ms
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
[0:] Threshold reached
[0:] +++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: is it smoother if you disabled the incremental loading?

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect the performance with that disabled, still very choppy - both scrolling up and scrolling down.

Comment: What platform and is it a device or simulator/emulator?

Comment: Oh dang, I thought I mentioned that!  Android 13 on a Pixel 6 and also in the Pixel 5 emulator (whatever version that runs), but I mainly test on the real device.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm seeing https://www.youtube.com/shorts/1irCkwYYiY4

Comment: I've experienced issues with FlexLayout when used with either ListView or CollectionView ItemTemplates. The issue can lead to unresponsive or unpredictable mouse behavior with the mouse events not always going down to your item template. Consider replacing your FlexLayout with Grid, HorizontalLayout, VerticalLayout, etc. The behavior is supposedly better in the upcoming 8.0.

Comment: It's actually in a Grid in the video, I switched over to a FlexLayout before posting the question to see if it was maybe the layout causing the issue before I brought it up.  I'll try a VerticalLayout and see if that improves anything.  Thanks!  

EDIT:  Seems a CollectionView won't accept a StackLayout.

Comment: I posted some Debug Output from when I scroll down a bit, not sure if it is helpful or not but it is here: https://gist.github.com/ReticentRobot/7c386c01d3ba5da51a8209b10a465774

Comment: Project is posted here if anyone is willing to build and try themselves, lol: https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc

Comment: I've noticed that you have too much data on page loads, and you can consider paging them.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on that?  I originally had it pulling 20 and loading more when down to 5 but still had the problem then, I increased it to 50 hoping loading more posts up front might help - is that what is meant by loading too much data on page loads?  I'll try cutting it down to the default (10), but I'd like to keep the incremental loading if possible.

Comment: Okay, so pagination means something different than I thought, lol - but I think I already have that implemented anyway(?). I tried reducing the initial load to 10 and threshold at 2, but still the same issue.  Even tried 5 and 1 and still the same (big stutter loading with that setting due to low threshold) - but I can especially tell its a problem when scrolling up.  It almost seems like it's a problem with the UI loading/unloading elements as I scroll up and down?

Comment: I noticed that your page has several converters at the same time, which is also the reason why your page loads slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought for sure no more were coming :)

I disabled all four converters, but it had no effect on performance.  (Also had the same issue when I removed everything except for the title previously, which had no converters running on it).  The json loads are generally about 46KB each (20 posts at a 5 post threshold for incrementally loading another 20) - plus the issue is even worse scrolling up than down back to content already loaded.  I don't think 46KB is much but maybe it is in this context.  I've been chatting on Discord with another MAUI dev who is saying they

Comment: ran into the same problems and so they gave up and switched to Kotlin even though it was a pain to start over and learn the new language/paradigm.  I'd much prefer to stick with MAUI, but I'm just not seeing any reason for this stuttering to be happening during scrolling? 

Surely I'm not the only person using a CollectionView to scroll through incrementally loading content from an API/json?

Comment: Please see UPDATE in Question, may be something relevant to go off in there?

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12130 - after I troubleshoot these messages I may look into trying .NET 8 preview to see if that helps at all.

Comment: Setting Binding to OneTime also had no effect on performance (per https://www.sharpnado.com/xamarin-forms-maui-collectionview-performance-the-10-golden-rule/).  I also replaced my one row with a "*" height (since it can be either one or two lines long depending on the text length) with a fixed height (despite that being ugly AF), but again - no discernable performance gain.

Comment: I want to know how you implement paging, I think you have a really large amount of data per page.

Comment: If I'm not still misunderstanding what is meant by paging then I'm using the API limit option to limit the amount of posts being pulled per request.  For example, I have `public string endpoint { get; set; } = "/posts?limit=" + Constants.PageSize;` in my VM, and have tried setting Constants.PageSize to various sizes between 5 to 50 at a time (max limit from the API) with no differences in performance.  Typically I'm trying to use 20 at a time with a remaining items threshold of 5, but have experimented with a variety of different page sizes and threshold limits. Performance doesn't change.